# How Run Command on One Software With php

Tags: php, shell, command-line, window

I want to run a software under Windows using PHP, and then enter the command  in the command line and return the result. 
Is it possible ?
If it is not possible what programming language can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Program Execution commands in PHP for this. You can refer [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php)